# Cannot Run Any C++ Program with Classes in Multiple Files in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, file, class

I cannot run any C++ program which requires to place classes in separate files in Code Blocks. An error appears, stating "no such file or directory" in 2main.

Here are my codes:

Codes of main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sally.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Sally sallyObject;
sallyObject.printCrap();

}
```

Codes of sally.h:

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H


class Sally
{
public:
Sally();
void printCrap();
protected:
private:
};

#endif // SALLY_H
```

Codes of sally.cpp:

```
#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Sally::Sally()
{

}

void Sally::printCrap()
{
cout<<"Did someone say steak"<<endl;

}
```

Please, help me. I am new to C++. I am totally stuck! :(

Comment: Are the three files in the same directory?

Comment: There are three files in the same project. I am learning C++ by watching the tutorials of New Boston. I have done everything right as shown in the Tutorial 42 (youtube.com/…), but the program is not running. The same thing happens in case of tutorial 15 (youtube.com/…). Please, someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my own problem! I have gone to Settings>Compiler>Reset Defaults. Then I click OK. All programs with classes in multiple files are running flawlessly in my computer!

Answer (score 1):

In Code Blocks you have to create new project. For what you are doing I would just make it a console application. That will setup the main file. From there you just add file and include the new files in the debug or release mode. If you created the three files without making a project it won't compile them together. I ran your code in Code Blocks in Ubuntu and it produces the string "Did someone say steak."

Read http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project for a visual representation of building a project in Code Blocks.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I created project on Code Blocks. In fact, I have learnt some basics about the software. I am learning C++ by watching the tutorials of New Boston. I have done everything right as shown in the Tutorial 42 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RP4f9beidc&list=PL3072B098E8A80AAF&index=42), but the program is not running. The same thing happens in case of tutorial 15 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTip15BHVZc&index=15&list=PL516351DED5DECCA8). Please, someone help me to solve this isse.

Comment: Your question says sally.h but your code says #include "Sally.h". Are you calling sally with the right case?

Comment: It really seems that your files are just not in the same project. They might be in the same folder but that is not the same thing. The link I posted is very straightforward. You need to create a project and you can add the other two files to it and add them to the debug and release builds. Your code worked for me when I did it that way so I do not think you are looking for any kind of syntax error.

Comment: I have done everything that you have said. My code runs on ideone.com, but it still doesn't run on Code Blocks. Can you suggest another IDE similar to Code Blocks for Windows 7?

Comment: When I work in Windows I generally use Visual Studio. They have express editions which are free. I am sure there are a lot out there which work in Windows but Visual Studio can easily setup the files you have in a project and run.